# Create form in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

I was assigned a task to create a form in SSRS. This form is used by finance dept submit to government quarterly. The sample form looks like a tax form. When end user input data the form will automatically calculate the result. I have never done this kind task before. I only used SSRS to create table or matrix reports. Can anybody give me some ideas? 
Thanks.

Comment: The only way to get input for an SSRS report is via parameters. If they want to type something into a form cell, and have the calculation update based on that value, build this in Excel.

Comment: Thanks Richard. Yes I think excel is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot really create forms in SSRS. The only input that users can do is from a report parameter. I would suggest using Microsoft Access, that way you can import any data from the necessary databases (if you need to use database) and create a form there.

Or use a simple Excel calculation.

Answer (score 0):

You can successfully use SSRS as a forms interface. SSRS is actually nice for SIMPLE forms solutions. Search how and you will be able to change the "VIEW REPORT" button to Submit , or any thing else you want it to say.

You can also easily embed reports in SharePoint (No add-ins) using the Page Viewer web part. Use "https://YOURREPORTSERVERNAME.YourReportName?rs:Embed=True" to hide the report navigation bar..